# develop lock screen for windows mobile phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm still beginner level. But I really look forward how to create the lock screen wallpaper using the Visual Studio SDK or the Blend 4. Really need you guys help.

Comment: I think you need something more like Photoshop to create it (if any tool). It's just an image.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the lock screen wallpaper using C# code. Although you can create images using `WritableBitmap` and save them to `PicturesHub`, from where the user can change the lock screen wallpaper himself. I hope the following link helps you: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/184613.aspx/1